# Authorization fail

Tags: plugin-elementapi, authentication, plugin-duktoauth

I am trying to being authorized at Chanel Adviser but it's showing error, "invalid_client".

I am invoking this URL :

```
https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token?client_id=qgonsl3lqy4qbje8pxl294stbc8m7ne3&response_type=token&scope=orders+inventory&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.redirecturl.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&state=insertantiforgerytoken
```

I am following there official process described here:

```
https://developer.channeladvisor.com/authorization/oauth-2-0-authorization-flow
```

Anybody can help me where I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention in the post, but you tagged the question with [Dukt oAuth](https://dukt.net/oauth).

If you're trying to connect with that, Channel Advisor isn't a 1st or 3rd party Dukt oAuth provider.  You can see a list of the available ones here: https://dukt.net/oauth/providers

You'd need to right an oAuth Channel Advisor [Craft plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) in order for it to work.